# Filter between Combobox in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I create an application with powerapps, and i need to filter between 3 combobox "Country" " Project" and "Contract" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4WtO.png). Like you can see in the picture. I want to display the projects associated with the chosen country & Contract, and the sae thing for the 3 combobox. How can i do this please ?
And i have another question, is it necessary that the 3 columns must be in the same sharepoint list so that I can filter between them ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

To filter with multiple combobox:

```
Filter('galleryName',combobox.selected.value='columnName',combobox2.selected.value='columnName2',combobox3.selected.value='columnName3')
```

Please be carefull about the type of the values..

If you want to filter between columns that are not in the same List you can using the function AddColumns()..Search it in the documents, if you have problems please tell me.
Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

In this case gallery shows only records that match in all comboboxes

```
Filter('GalleryName',
   'columnCounty'= ComboboxCountry.Selected.Value 
   &&  'colunmPorject'= ComboBoxProject.Selected.Value
   && 'ColunmContract'=ComboBoxProject.Selected.Value
)
```

With code below the gallery shows all the records that match, for example if ComboboxCountry and ComboboxContract are empty, all the projects that match in ComboboxProject are shown

```
Filter('GalleryName',
   StartsWith('columnCounty', ComboboxCountry.Selected.Value)
   &&  StartsWith('colunmPorject', ComboBoxProject.Selected.Value)
   && StartsWith('ColunmContract', ComboBoxProject.Selected.Value)
)
```